# Custom Google Map Markers with different sizes

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Working on getting other map points to populate on a Google map using different map markers, but the PNG's of the map markers have different sizes.

I'm not too sure how to resize the other map markers. I implementing this off of code that was already there, so I don't know if I have to re-write this thing or if there is some place where I can pass the correct image size of the poi-marker.png

Here's what I have. Overall, it's working correctly, just need to know how to resize the poi-marker.png image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
 var styles = [
{
 "featureType": "poi",
 "elementType": "labels",
 "stylers": [
{ "visibility": "off" }
 ]
 },{

   "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
   { "visibility": "off" }
   ]

      },{
    }

   ];

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.452636,-91.107285);
   var mapOptions = {
   center: myLatlng,
   zoom: 13,
   scrollwheel: false,
 };



 var locations = [
['<div class="dealerinfobox"><span class="dealername"><strong>Richards Honda</strong></span><br />7791 Florida Boulevard Baton Rouge, LA 70806</div><a target="_blank" class="directionslink button small-button" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Richards+Honda/@30.452314,-91.107482,15z/">Get Directions</a>', 30.452636,-91.107285,'/path/to/folder/images/map-marker.png'],

['<div class="dealerinfobox"><span class="dealername"><strong>Broadmoor/Sherwood Forest</strong></span><br />2 Miles</div>', 30.4455406,-91.0385525,'/path/to/folder/images/poi-marker.png'],

['<div class="dealerinfobox"><span class="dealername"><strong>College Drive</strong></span><br /></div>', 30.4281267,-91.1363998,'/path/to/folder/images/poi-marker.png'],

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
map: map,
icon: locations[i][3]
});

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
 })(marker, i));
}


 map.setOptions({styles: styles});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The main map marker (map-marker.png) is a different size than the POI markers (poi-marker.png). The POI markers are 30x30 and I'm trying to set the dimensions of the poi-marker.png's to 30x30.

Comment: 1. What is the existing size of the POI marker?  2. What size do you want it to be? 3. Do you want the markers to be their "native" size?  4. Do they have different "native" sizes that you want to be the same?

Comment: I updated my OP. Basically I'm trying to get the POI markers to be 30x30 which is different from the main map marker.

Comment: Can you provide links to the markers? (unless loanburger's post answers your question).  Another option would be to resize the POI markers to be 30x30 in an image editor (that would avoid the overhead of the browser resizing the image)

Answer (score 1):

You can resize a marker by doing this:

```
 var image = 
 {
     url: 'images/beachflag.png',
     // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
     size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
     // The origin for this image is 0,0.
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.LastLat, data.LastLon),
                data: data,
                title: data.Description,
                icon: image
            });
```

Note the icon (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) - you specify an icon image, anchor and  give it a size.

More information on complex icons here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, Try this:

Add a css class to your location items which are poi then in your loop see if the current item has that class then change icon size accordingly:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
{
   var iconImage;

    // Check if the current item has a poi class
    if(locations[i].indexOf('yourPOIClass') > -1)
    {     
       iconImage  = 
       {
            url: locations[i][3],   
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),  // set POI size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),  
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
       };
    }
    else
    {
      iconImage = 
       {
            url: locations[i][3],   
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),    // set other marker size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),  
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
       };
    }

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map,
         icon: iconImage 
       });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
 })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: This would work if I was using the same map marker icon for all of map point, but there are different map marker icons that I am using; one for the main point and the other for points of interest (POI). The POI markers are a different size than the main marker.

Comment: Can you not just loop through your data and based on their type create a marker specific to that type then use the correct icon?

Comment: It's possible. The only issue is that this original script wasn't written by me, so I'm not sure if doing so will break something. It seems that whenever I change somehting in there, something else breaks (I think there is some search enabled...somewhere) so I'm trying to keep everything in tact. Which is why I'm not sure if I need to re-write this or what.